# Row Count for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to count or return the last index of a `DataGrid` row? Apparently there's isn't a `DataGrid.Count()` property. I searched everywhere and I can't find an answer.

I could create a variable and use `i++` as a counter for `Row` count, but doesn't a `DataGrid` has a built-in solution?

Comment: You shouldn't be counting the datagrid row but the collection of items attached to the datasource

Comment: The real question is what you need it for. If it's databound, like proper WPF, why would you care for a index?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `DataGrid.Items.Count` to get the number if items.

Answer (score 3):

store the count in a variable

```
 int num=dataGrid.Items.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Items.Count returns 1 when you Datagrid is editable. This don't work for me.

Try this:

```
int num=dataGrid.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

As TBohnen.jnr mentioned you should count the items in the bounded datasource. You can retrieve the datasource by casting `dataGrid.DataContext` to the appropriate `Type` (List, IEnumerable, or any other Type) and call `.Count` on that object. It shouldn't be very hard...

Comment: DataContext would usually not be an IEnumerable (or a collection), and IEnumberable doesn't have a Count property.